# How to make curly braces with several equations?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am trying to type the following equations in LaTeX:[image: equations with curly brace]

What I currently have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{C}{V}=\sin\gamma\implies C=V\cdot\sin\gamma\\
\sin\gamma=\cos\gamma\cdot\dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies C=V\cdot\cos\gamma\cdot\dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}\\
\left.\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}=\dfrac{C_D}{C_L}
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

So, as you can see I could not manage to put the second curly brace properly.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Take care to use `\cos`, `\sin`, etc.; these look much better and are the actual sine/cosine functions. (Of course other such operators exist, but I'll leave that to creative experimentation.)

Comment: Yes, I was using \cos and \sin, but since I copy-pasted it, I probably missed to copy the '\'. Thank you @SeanAllred for your remark and recommendation. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nest `aligned` properly; I defined a `compute` environment for convenience, also removing as much useless space as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{compute}
 {\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\!\aligned}
 {\endaligned\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{compute}
  \begin{compute}
    \begin{compute}
    \frac{C}{V}=\sin\gamma\to C=V\sin\gamma\\
    \sin\gamma=\cos\gamma\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}
    \end{compute}
  \to C=V\cos\gamma\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}\\
  \frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}=\frac{C_D}{C_L}
  \end{compute}
\to C=V\frac{C_D}{C_L}\cos\gamma\\
V=\sqrt{\frac{W}{S}\frac{2}{\rho}\frac{1}{C_L}\cos\gamma}
\end{compute}
\to C=\sqrt{\frac{W}{S}\frac{2}{\rho}\frac{C_D^2}{C_L^3}\cos^3\gamma}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg for your reply. It works very well and I like the way that it takes less space.

Answer (score 10):

The following solution uses nested `array` environments, with the contents of all columns right-aligned. The innermost `array`, which is terminated by the first large curly brace, features a single column of type `r`. The next `array` features two such columns; note that its lower-left cell is empty. The outermost array also has two columns of type `r`, and its lower-left cell is also empty. Observe that the final `C=...` term is not encased in an `array`, as none is required.

The code uses `\to` directives, since that's what is in the screenshot you posted; of course, feel free to use `\implies` (aka `\Rightarrow`) if that suits your style better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters here
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\dfrac" macro
% \usepackage{mathptmx} % -- optional, if you want Times Roman font family
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default value: 5pt
\left.\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    \left.\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
        \left.\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
        \dfrac{C}{V}=\sin\gamma\to C=V \sin\gamma\\
        \sin\gamma=\cos\gamma\,\dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}
        \end{array}\right\}
    & \to C=V\cos\gamma\,\dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}\\
    & \dfrac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}=\dfrac{C_D}{C_L}\\
    \end{array}\right\}
& \to C= V\dfrac{C_D}{C_L}\cos\gamma\\
& V=\sqrt{\dfrac{W}{S}\dfrac{2}{\rho}\dfrac{1}{C_L}\cos\gamma}
\end{array}\right\}
\to C=\sqrt{\dfrac{W}{S}\dfrac{2}{\rho}\dfrac{C_D^2}{C_L^3} \cos^3\gamma}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want the lowermost expression, `V=\sqrt{...}`, to be shifted a bit to the left, so that it's directly below the large curly brace, you may achieve this goal by (a) loading the `mathtools` package and (b) encasing the entire `V=\sqrt{...}` expression in a `\mathllap{...}` macro, i.e, by writing

```
\mathllap{V=\sqrt{\dfrac{W}{S}\dfrac{2}{\rho}\dfrac{1}{C_L}\cos\gamma}}
```

in the bottom-right cell of the outermost `array` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mico for your answer, it works perfectly. I think I will use \to instead of \implies on this set of equations. Also, thank you again for finishing/typing the whole equations.